# Newbie Issue with X11 Double buffering. Request help with code

Tags: 2d-graphics

I botched together the following code to do a simple rotating radar display.

1. How can I eliminate the flicker of the line being drawn and then drawn over? Can I use double buffering somehow?
2. How can I get mouse and keyboard inputs and process/parse them?

My goal is to read angle and distance data from an ultrasonic sensor and display that as a sweep. This data comes from an Arduino with an ultrasonic rangefinder mounted on a servo sweeping backwards and forwards 180 degrees. I also can't quite get the math right. I'd like it to go from 0 to 180, left to right and back depending on the angle data from the Arduino. 0 Deg is 90 Deg off to the right. So I know I have to offset it by 180 Deg but am hopeless at math. The sweep would have to start at 270 Deg and sweep through to 0 Deg. I will have to learn how to read the serial port and parse the data for the display.

Here is my code. I used a tutorial as a base and kind of guessed my way through.

```
/*
 * simple-drawing.c - demonstrate drawing of pixels, lines, arcs, etc.
 *                    on a window. All drawings are done in black color
 *                    over a white background.
 */

#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     /* getenv(), etc. */
#include <unistd.h>     /* sleep(), etc.  */

// Include math library functions.
#include <math.h>

/*
 * function: create_simple_window. Creates a window with a white background
 *           in the given size.
 * input:    display, size of the window (in pixels), and location of the window
 *           (in pixels).
 * output:   the window's ID.
 * notes:    window is created with a black border, 2 pixels wide.
 *           the window is automatically mapped after its creation.
 */
Window
create_simple_window(Display* display, int width, int height, int x, int y)
{
  int screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
  int win_border_width = 2;
  Window win;

  /* create a simple window, as a direct child of the screen's */
  /* root window. Use the screen's black and white colors as   */
  /* the foreground and background colors of the window,       */
  /* respectively. Place the new window's top-left corner at   */
  /* the given 'x,y' coordinates.                              */
  win = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screen_num),
                            x, y, width, height, win_border_width,
                            BlackPixel(display, screen_num),
                            WhitePixel(display, screen_num));   

  /* make the window actually appear on the screen. */
  XMapWindow(display, win);

  /* flush all pending requests to the X server. */
  XFlush(display);

  return win;
}

GC
create_gc(Display* display, Window win, int reverse_video)
{
  GC gc;                /* handle of newly created GC.  */
  unsigned long valuemask = 0;      /* which values in 'values' to  */
                    /* check when creating the GC.  */
  XGCValues values;         /* initial values for the GC.   */
  unsigned int line_width = 2;      /* line width for the GC.       */
  int line_style = LineSolid;       /* style for lines drawing and  */
  int cap_style = CapButt;      /* style of the line's edje and */
  int join_style = JoinBevel;       /*  joined lines.       */
  int screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);

  gc = XCreateGC(display, win, valuemask, &values);
  if (gc < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "XCreateGC: \n");
  }

  /* allocate foreground and background colors for this GC. */
  if (reverse_video) {
    XSetForeground(display, gc, WhitePixel(display, screen_num));
    XSetBackground(display, gc, BlackPixel(display, screen_num));
  }
  else {
    XSetForeground(display, gc, BlackPixel(display, screen_num));
    XSetBackground(display, gc, WhitePixel(display, screen_num));
  }

  /* define the style of lines that will be drawn using this GC. */
  XSetLineAttributes(display, gc,
                     line_width, line_style, cap_style, join_style);

  /* define the fill style for the GC. to be 'solid filling'. */
  XSetFillStyle(display, gc, FillSolid);

  return gc;
}

void
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Display* display;     /* pointer to X Display structure.           */
  int screen_num;       /* number of screen to place the window on.  */
  Window win;           /* pointer to the newly created window.      */
  unsigned int display_width,
               display_height;  /* height and width of the X display.        */
  unsigned int width, height;   /* height and width for the new window.      */
  char *display_name = getenv("DISPLAY");  /* address of the X display.      */
  GC gc;            /* GC (graphics context) used for drawing    */
                    /*  in our window.               */

  // Added code to select simple black or white color to draw.
  Colormap screen_colormap;     /* color map to use for allocating colors.   */
  XColor black, white;
                                /* used for allocation of the given color    */
                                /* map entries.                              */
  Status rc;                    /* return status of various Xlib functions.  */

// Johns stuff. This code draws a line from starting co-ordinates at an angle
// 

int angle=0;
int x1,x2,y1,y2;
int px,py;

// End

  /* open connection with the X server. */
  display = XOpenDisplay(display_name);
  if (display == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: cannot connect to X server '%s'\n",
            argv[0], display_name);
    exit(1);
  }

  /* get the geometry of the default screen for our display. */
  screen_num = DefaultScreen(display);
  display_width = DisplayWidth(display, screen_num);
  display_height = DisplayHeight(display, screen_num);

  /* make the new window occupy 1/9 of the screen's size. */
  width = (display_width / 2); 
  height = (display_height / 2);
  printf("window width - '%d'; height - '%d'\n", width, height);

  /* create a simple window, as a direct child of the screen's   */
  /* root window. Use the screen's white color as the background */
  /* color of the window. Place the new window's top-left corner */
  /* at the given 'x,y' coordinates.                             */
  win = create_simple_window(display, width, height, 50, 50);

  /* allocate a new GC (graphics context) for drawing in the window. */
  gc = create_gc(display, win, 0);
  XSync(display, False);

  // Following 3 lines needed or else we just see white background.

  /* catch expose events */
  XSelectInput(display, win, ExposureMask);

  /* wait for the expose event */
  XEvent ev;
  XNextEvent(display, &ev);

  // Follwing code borrowed to get colors to draw.    
  /* get access to the screen's color map. */
  screen_colormap = DefaultColormap(display, DefaultScreen(display));

  /* allocate the set of colors we will want to use for the drawing. */
  rc = XAllocNamedColor(display, screen_colormap, "black", &black, &black);
  if (rc == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "XAllocNamedColor - failed to allocated 'black' color.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  rc = XAllocNamedColor(display, screen_colormap, "white", &white, &white);
  if (rc == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "XAllocNamedColor - failed to allocated 'white' color.\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* draw one pixel near each corner of the window */
  XDrawPoint(display, win, gc, 5, 5);
  XDrawPoint(display, win, gc, 5, height-5);
  XDrawPoint(display, win, gc, width-5, 5);
  XDrawPoint(display, win, gc, width-5, height-5);

// Do our display. Loop forever because I don't know how to process keystrokes.
// If we start from the center of the display, 0 is to the right (E), 90 is to the
// bottom (S), 180 (W),270 (N). Don't quite know how to "rotate" the "beam" 180 Deg.
// Needs double buffering to remove the flicker.
// I would like to make a separate subroutine eg: DrawRadar( int angle, int distance);

  x1=width / 2;     //Find center of display.
  y1=height / 2;
  px=x1;            // Previous X and Y
  py=y1;

while(1){

  for(angle=0; angle < 360; angle++)
  {

  // Distance set to 150 pixels. Radar returns value up to 3300 mm.
  // Will have to scale down. 
    x2=x1 + cos((angle * M_PI) / 180) * 150;   // Must convert to radians.
    y2=y1 + sin((angle * M_PI) / 180) * 150;   //  "     "      "    "

    XSetForeground(display, gc, black.pixel);  // 
    XDrawLine(display, win, gc, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    px=x2;
    py=y2;
    XFlush(display);      // Display what we've drawn.
    usleep(3500);         // Wait so eye can see it.
    XSetForeground(display, gc, white.pixel);  // Rub out the line we just drew.
    XDrawLine(display, win, gc, x1, y1, px ,py);
    XFlush(display);      // Causes flickering but only way at the moment.
    XSetForeground(display, gc, black.pixel);
    usleep(3500);

  }
}
// End. Never get past here.

  /* flush all pending requests to the X server. */
  XFlush(display);
  XSync(display, False);

  /* make a delay for a short period. */
  sleep(4);

  /* close the connection to the X server. */
  XCloseDisplay(display);
}
```

I'm simply trying to draw a moving line without flicker. I understand the concept but am a crap coder. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The Unix & Linux stack exchange forum may be a better spot to post this. Most folks here are working with OpenGL, DirectX, Vulkan, etc.